# How to create a method that give all packages name on the current project

Tags: java

I would create a methode that give all **packages name** on the **current project**.

[image: The code below show the package system]

I need to show the packages of the project

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: ok, i need to affiche packages name of my current project exemple: org.sara.show ,org.sara.show.ask ... –

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post code as images, post them as text (indented by four spaces to form a code block). Also try to describe exactly what you want to achieve and how your current code fails to do that.

Comment: ok, thank you and sorry for language my English is not well, thank you so much for <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using reflexion, getting all your class name, then from their package getting the parents package.
Not very clean but it works ...

```
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.ResourcesScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.reflections.util.FilterBuilder;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

private static Collection<String> getListPackageNames(String pMainPackage) {
    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false /* don't exclude Object.class */), new ResourcesScanner())
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
            .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix(pMainPackage))));
    // Get all classes
    Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    // Get all packages of those classes while removing duplicate
    final Set<Package> listClassPackages = classes.stream().map(c -> c.getPackage()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // Extract package name while loving up to get the intermediate packages.
    final Set<String> listPackageNames = new HashSet<>();
    for (Package classPackage:listClassPackages) {
        String packageName = classPackage.getName();
        while (!packageName.equals(pMainPackage)) {
            // Add it to the list
            listPackageNames.add(packageName);
            // Then move up
            final int index = packageName.lastIndexOf('.');
            packageName = packageName.substring(0, index);
        }
    }
    return listPackageNames;
}
```

You pass your project main package as parameter

```
Collection<String> listPackages = getListPackageNames("com.mycompany.mainpackage");
// Print the names
listPackages.stream().forEach(p->System.out.println(p));
```

Comment: thank you very much i will tray that , thank youuuuu <3 <3

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept if any of the answer match your need.

Comment: yes of caurse, i am  traying the answer and i will tell you , thank you so much bro .

Answer (score 2):

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185142/get-package-names-using-java-reflections?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I think you mean packages of classes that was written by you. If you don't know Reflection API, you could use File in java. For expample use `Files.walkFileTree()` . Follow the tree and check only files with java extension, if it's `.java` file than use

```
Path absolute = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
Path relative =  Paths.get("path to your projects folder");
Path relativePath = relative.relativize(absolute);
String result = relativePath.toString().replaceAll("\\.", "") // it would be package name
```